# a href onclick not working on some pages

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

I have the following code, i use v similar code on many pages but on this particular page it simply doeasn't work in either ie or ff

here's the code:

```
<form action='/productView.html' method=post name=prod_form>
<a  href='javascript:;' onclick='document.forms['prod_form'].submit(); return false;' class='button101' style='margin-left:92px;'>".$button_text."</a>
<input type=hidden name=action value='".$button_text."'>
<input type=hidden name=PRid value=".$databack3[PRid].">
<INPUT type='hidden' name='cat_id' value=".$databack3[prodcatID].">
<INPUT type='hidden' name='for_user_id' value=".$for_user_id.">
<input type=hidden name=source value=".$source."></form>
```

However, if i change to normal button as below it works fine:

```
<form action='/productView.html' method=post name=prod_form>
<input type=submit name=action class=button99 value='".$button_text."' style='margin-left:85px;'
<input type=hidden name=PRid value=".$databack3[PRid].">
<INPUT type='hidden' name='cat_id' value=".$databack3[prodcatID].">
<INPUT type='hidden' name='for_user_id' value=".$for_user_id.">
<input type=hidden name=source value=".$source."></form>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem;

```
onclick='document.forms['prod_form'].submit(); return false;'
```

Use regular quotes for you HTML arguments and you´ll be fine.

As it seems you´re using PHP to create a string with your HTML you´d try this to escape the quotes;

```
onclick=\"document.forms['prod_form'].submit(); return false;\"
```

Answer (score 8):

Wrap the content of the `onclick` attribute in double-quotes (");

```
onclick="document.forms['prod_form'].submit(); return false;"
```

Just to be clear, it's not that attributes **require** double-quotes, but you can't have the same kind of quotes inside your outer quotes, unless you escape them.

For example:

- OK: `<a href="#" onclick="do('this');">bar</a>`
- OK: `<a href="#" onclick='do("this");'>bar</a>`
- OK: `<a href="#" onclick="do(\"this\");">bar</a>`
- OK: `<a href="#" onclick='do(\'this\');'>bar</a>`
- **Not** OK: `<a href="#" onclick='do('this');'>bar</a>`
- **Not** OK: `<a href="#" onclick="do("this");">bar</a>`

Answer (score 3):

its not able to detect `form name` because that too is in `single quotes`.

```
<a  href='#' onclick='document.forms["prod_form"].submit(); return false;' 
           class='button101' style='margin-left:92px;'>".$button_text."</a>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QFe3L/

Answer (score 1):

It is just because of using single quotes. 
Just change your

```
onclick='document.forms['prod_form'].submit(); return false;'
```

to

```
onclick="document.forms['prod_form'].submit(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<b><form action='/productView.html' method=post name=prod_form> <a 
   href='javascript:;' onclick="document.forms['prod_form'].submit();
   return false;" class='button101'
   style='margin-left:92px;'>".$button_text."</a> <input type=hidden
   name=action value='".$button_text."'> <input type=hidden name=PRid
   value=".$databack3[PRid]."> <INPUT type='hidden' name='cat_id'
   value=".$databack3[prodcatID]."> <INPUT type='hidden'
   name='for_user_id' value=".$for_user_id."> <input type=hidden
   name=source value=".$source."></form>

   Hope it works

</b>
```